# Import and use a variable from an external file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, import

This is code that is executable and works correctly. It aims to select for example `Serie A` and `Atalanta`, and then print an example of template.

I would like to import and use the contents of the external Template.py file inside the Main.py file. I would like to invoke the Template.py file in `def article1` (I need it in that exact location).

The content of the external Template.py file is `template1 = f "The coach {article} {subject}"` and `template2`. If you use `template1 = f "The coach {article} {subject}"` and `template2` directly inside the function `def article1`, then my app works fine.

**WHAT I WANT?** But for reasons of order and cleanliness of the code, I would like to report `template1 = f "The trainer {article}` in an external file and call it exactly in the same exact position in def article1). Consequently I would like to get the same output that I would get by inserting template1 = f "The coach {article} {subject}" and template2 directly in the main file in def article1, with the difference that I would like to extract the template from an external file

**After importing, how can I call it and use template1 and template2 individually?**

(Obviously this is just an example, later the Template.py file will contain many templates and not just one

Template.py file that contains the template

```
template1 = f"L'allenatore {article} {subject}"
template2 = f"Il direttore {article} {subject}"
```

Main file

```
import Template
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")


####################

tournament=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
tournament.place(x=15, y=15)
tournament['value'] = ["Serie A", "Serie B"]
tournament.set("Tournament")

def on_tournament_selected(event):
    # Clear the entry boxes: aggiunto io
    team.delete(0,'end') 
    
    req_teams = [] # For all the required teams
    sel_tournament = tournament.get() # Get the tournament
    
    # get the names for selected gender
    for _team in teams.items(): # Go through all the teams in the dictionary
        key = _team[0] # Get the key
        value = _team[1] # Get the value 
        if value['Tournament'] == sel_tournament: # If Tournament of the loop-ed team is our selected tourname, then 
            req_teams.append(key)
    
    team.config(values=req_teams) # Change the values of the combobox

tournament.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_tournament_selected)

#############

team=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
team.place(x=200, y=15)
team.set("Teams")

text = tk.Text(root,width=43,height=2)
text.place(x=15, y=50)


def getArticle(subject):
    for key, value in article_words.items():
        if nouns[subject] == value:
            return key

def printTeam():
    subject = team.get()
    article = getArticle(subject)

    def articolo1():
        #Here I would like to import the template from another file
        Template()

        text.insert(tk.END, template1 or template2)

    articolo1()

button2 = Button(root, text="Print", command = printTeam)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=15, y=100)

#DICT
teams = {
            "Atalanta": {
                "Nome Squadra": "Atalanta",
                "Tournament": "Serie A",
                "Città": "Bergamo",
        },


            "Bologna": {
                "Nome Squadra": "Bologna",
                "Tournament": "Serie A",
                "Città": "Bologna",
        }
   }
       
                      
                 

nouns = {

        "Atalanta": {"genere" : "femminile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "si"},
        "Bologna": {"genere" : "maschile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "no"},
        }



article_words = {
    
            "del" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo": "no"
            },
            
            "dello" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare"
            },
                      
            "della" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare"
            },
                      
            "delle" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "plurale"
            },

            "dell'" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo" : "si"
            },                
        }

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Couldn't you just move the import into `def articolo1():`?

Comment: @Matt Clarke Yes. That's what I asked for. How can I do? I am new to Python. Thank you

Comment: You can literally move`import Template` inside `def articolo1():`. The imports do not have to be at the top

Comment: I wouldn't bother though, it is perfectly fine where it is.

Comment: @MattClarke Ok, but i get this error with your help:     template1 = f"L'allenatore {article} {subject}"
NameError: name 'article' is not defined

Comment: That's because `article` and `subject` don't exist in Template.py, so the f-string cannot find them. I would change the templates to regular strings with placholders, like so `template1 = "L'allenatore {} {}"` and when you use it you can do `template1.format(article, subject)`

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 0):

```
def printTeam():
    values = {
        'subject': team.get(),
        'article': getArticle(team.get())
    }

    def articolo1():
        template = Template.template1

        text.insert(tk.END, template.format(**values))

    articolo1()
```

Where `template1 = "L'allenatore {article} {subject}"`

f-strings are evaluated immediately, so if the variables are not defined then you will get `NameError`. Templates.py cannot "see" the definitions of `article` and `subject` in the main file, so you get NameError.

Comment: That's no good. That's not what I'm looking for. Excuse me. In the external Template file, I must have # template1 = f "The coach {article} {subject}", not template1 = "The coach {} {}". THE REASON? I need to have # template1 = f "The coach {article} {subject}" for the sake of clarity and visibility, otherwise it's impossible to create the templates if I can't see what to put in them. Do you have other solutions? Thank you

Comment: @Jas_99: updated answer based on your comment. How about that?

Comment: We get close to what I'm looking for, but ".format (article = article, subject = subject))" doesn't convince me. Isn't there some other way? The code in my question is just an example, later I will implement it by adding other grammar elements (like article, subject and others like it), so the row will stretch a lot with other grammar elements. Your logic construction is right, but it doesn't look very clean and also it's a bit repetitive in format. Is there a way to not have to repeat article and subject in format? Or don't use format but use something else? Thank you

Comment: If it is going to get complicated then perhaps look at a templating library like mako? I don't have any experience of using it, so cannot really comment on how good it is but it might be worth a look.

Comment: Updated to use dictionary

Comment: Now I get an error: 'article': getArticle (subject) NameError: name 'subject' is not defined

Comment: Oops - sorry! I'll fix it